The React Native application does not connect to the Centrifuge
let centrifuge = null;
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isNull(centrifuge)) return;
    centrifuge = new Centrifuge(
    "ws://localhost:8000/connection/websocket",
    { token: "<TOKEN>" }
    );
    
    centrifuge.on("connecting", function (ctx) {
    setConectionsState('connecting - ' + ctx.reason);
    }).on("connected", function (ctx) {
    setConectionsState('connected ' + ctx);
    }).on("disconnected", function (ctx) {
    setConectionsState('disconnected - ' + ctx.reason);
    }).connect();   
    
    const sub = centrifuge.newSubscription("<CHANNEL>"); 
    
    sub.on("publication", function (ctx) {
    document.title = ctx.data.value;
    setConectionsState(ctx.data.value);
    }).on("subscribing", function (ctx) {
    console.log('subscribing: ' + ctx.code + ', ' + ctx.reason);
    }).on("subscribed", function (ctx) {
    console.log('subscribed', ctx);
    }).on("unsubscribed", function (ctx) {
    console.log('unsubscribed: ' + ctx.code + ', ' + ctx.reason);
    }).subscribe();

}, [, centrifuge]);

centrifuge v 5.4.0
config.json:
{
  "admin": true,
  "token_hmac_secret_key": "173e68a3-e8aa-435f-8fdd-9630bf8a3956",
  "admin_password": "301da9a6-8b06-4953-8cb2-5aece6875989",
  "admin_secret": "b2390dc6-91db-49ca-9305-ec777fa907ac",
  "api_key": "aa6d39b8-1826-48dd-b53a-e9a3e772bd2c",
  "allowed_origins": ["*"],
  "allow_subscribe_for_client": true
}

i'm geniration token using python
when trying to establish a connection between the centrifuge and my application, the value always remains connecting, I made a default react app to check and everything works there, what's the error here?
